# Knowing what process is launching mailto on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, process, mailto

Something weird has been happening for a while and it is driving me crazy. Every time I start my computer (running Windows 10 Pro 1809) it starts opening the Mail app several times. It looks like a mailto link has been clicked. Changed to Firefox just to check whether is the app itself or something else, but it keeps happening. It looks like something is triggering the mailto to launch.

Is there a way for me to know which process is launching this so I can disable it?

Thanks in advance.

PS: let me know if you need any more information

Comment: What does changing to Firefox have to do with something that happens after reboot and presumably before you start the browser? Which browser is your main browser?

Comment: Check registry `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mailto\shell\open\command`

Comment: @harrymc. I did not say it has something to do with Firefox. I said that I thought had something to do with the Mail app

Comment: Thanks @Robert, I´ll check on that registry key and will get back to you

Answer (score 1):

Use [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns), from Microsoft's Sysinternals, to determine what processes are starting on bootup. Turn on *Options | Scan Options... | Check VirusTotal.com. In particular, check the *Logon*, *Winlogon*, *Scheduled Tasks* and *Services* for anything suspicious. Of course, there are occasional false positives from some engines at [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload), so don't stop or remove a process from auto-running until you've researched it and confirmed it is, indeed, undesired.

Also perform a *thorough* check for malware on your system, e.g. with [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mwb-download/) or [Kaspersky VRT](https://www.kaspersky.com/downloads/thank-you/free-virus-removal-tool) -- you might be hosting a [spambot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spambot), sending unsolicited email from your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and run Process Explorer from Microsoft (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)
2. In Process Explorer, search for your Mail app in the list of running processes and select it
3. Make sure that the processes are viewed as a process tree. I.e., the process list is formatted hierarchically with some processes shown as sub-processes (children) of other processes (parents). If the processes are not listed as a process tree, enable this from the View menu via the Show Process Tree (Ctrl + T) menu item.
4. Now you can see which process is the direct parent of the Mail app. This is the process that launched it.
5. Alternatively, right click the Mail app process and view its properties. Notice that the Parent process is listed there. Again, this parent is the process launched the Mail app.